Why does my shapefile color a different polygon than intended?
I have risk data which I would like to color on a map according to the risk level. I read a shapefile and a csv data file which I then merge. This works very well working with adm1 shapefile.
When I run the same script with adm2 shapefile, the results are completely weird: The polygons colored are way far from the polygon with data. I have the attached map 3 examples of the colored polygons and in black dot the location of the data.
I will appreciate if anyone can give a clue of what is going on, and if possible how to resolve this.
Python script used to produce the plot:
#!/home/zmumba/anaconda3/bin/python

import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap  # optional ?

map_df = gpd.read_file("/home/zmumba/DA/Dekad_Progs/Shapefiles/Lesotho/geoBoundaries-LSO-ADM2-all/geoBoundaries-LSO-ADM2.shx")
risks_df=pd.read_csv("/home/zmumba/DA/Dekad_Progs/Output/H1dRrisks.csv")

map_df["risk"] = map_df.merge(risks_df, left_on="shapeName", right_on="District")["risk"]

colors = {1: "green", 2: "yellow", 3: "orange", 4: "red"}  # or a list
labels = {1: "no risk", 2: "low risk", 3: "medium risk", 4: "high risk"}
catego = map_df["risk"].astype(str).str.cat(map_df["risk"].map(labels), sep="- ")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.title(f'Risk of Heavy 24hr Rain: 20-24Nov', y=1.04)

map_df.plot(
column=catego,
categorical=True,
edgecolor="k",
linewidths=0.8,
alpha=0.7,
cmap=ListedColormap([c for r,c in colors.items() if r in map_df["risk"].unique()]),
legend=True,
legend_kwds={
"title": "Risk Level",
"shadow": True,
"loc": "lower right",
"fontsize": 10,
},
ax=ax,
)
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.savefig('H1dRriskmap.png', dpi=300)

plt.show()

Just to add some clarification to my problem, 
The attached image shows the polygon numbers from the shapefile. Coloring 42 colors 41, coloring 43 colors 42.
The coordinates of 41, 42 and 43 are
-29.3892289999999,  28.3056183629316  -> 41
-29.2870792999999,  29.2715247780569  -> 42
-29.2255776170000,  27.6546474532047  -> 43

These coordinates are the centroids of the polygons taken from the shapefile itself. So it cannot be a problem of coordinates.
Could there be something wrong in the python code?
The code reads from a file  which is in the format:
"District","risk"
"name1",1
"name2",1
...
"name78",1

where 1 can b2 2, 3, or 4 depending on the risk level.
I would be glad to try doing the same thing in R, but the problem with R is, it will say "no package sf" and so on.

Without seeing what you expect it to look like, it's difficult to tell what the problem is.

The yellow is supposed to be on the black spot further to the right. When the yellow is expected at the right most it get placed where the black spot is. When the yellow spot is expected at the corner, north of the current yellow spot, it gets placed south of the current black spot.

Thank you all who may have looked at my problem. I have done this over two other countries. Over one of the two other countries, the problem persist. but over the other country, the problem does not manifest at all. This leads me to the most probable scenario that there is nothing wrong with the code. The problem most probably lies somewhere else, e.g. the formulation of the shapefile polygons. Thank you once again.

As I see it, your error is in fact in your python-code... here:
map_df["risk"] = map_df.merge(risks_df, left_on="shapeName", right_on="District")["risk"]

To clarify:
Both your dataframes map_df and risks_df are indexed by numeric values (0,1,2,3 ...).
If you run the merge ( map_df.merge(risks_df, ...)), it will return a new DataFrame with a new index (which is again a numeric index 0,1,2...).
Now if you do map_df["risk"] = map_df.merge(...)["risk"] you'll write the results of the merge based on their merge-index to the index-values in map_df.
This works because both indexes are numeric, but it is in no way guaranteed to be  correct!
Just check your results... I guess you'll find that the "risk" values are not correctly assigned.
To make sure you assign the values correctly, I'd suggest to replace the line above with something like this:
map_df = map_df.set_index("shapeName")
map_df["risks"] = risks_df.set_index("District")["risk"]


The suggested code fixes the problem. Thank you very much @raphael. I have a small problem that polygons 25 and 53 are coming out blank, and even if I put risk there, no color appears.

Nice to hear :-) to have a look at your follow up question i'd need access to the shapefile...

I have not been able to attach the shapefile, but you can get a zipped file here https://github.com/wmgeolab/geoBoundaries/raw/9469f09/releaseData/gbOpen/LSO/ADM2/geoBoundaries-LSO-ADM2-all.zip

Immediately after "map_df["risks"] = risks_df.set_index("District")["risk"]", I have put "map_dfp=map_df.take([-1,4], axis=1)" to have a dataframe with only the shapeName, risk and geometry.
This plots correctly, but I noticed that the two polygons which come out blank have no risk value. The issue is how these risk values are dropped.

After getting dataframe with only the shapename, risk and geometry
map_df["risks"] = map_df["risks"].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',,', ',1.0,') if type (x) == str else str (x))
Replaces ,, by nan and not 1.0 as intended.
map_df["risks"] = map_df["risks"].apply(lambda x: x.replace('nan', '1.0'))
Gives map_df with all polygons with a risk values, but map_df.plot( gives IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
Any clues, assistance?

Hello, after two days of working and searching, it turned out that two polygon names were misspelt, different from the name in the shapefile. this resulted in the polygons appearing blank on the map and not picking up any risk values. Otherwise the answer above settled the issue. I am sorry for this, and thanks @raphael.

Hey, sorry for not responding earlier... Glad to hear you got it working by yourselve!

I really appreciate your assistance @raphael.
